# How do I access SQLite database directly from DLL (without using app.config)?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, sqlite

I'm trying to connect to and use an SQLite database file from a DLL.  So far I have the following

```
        ASSEMBLY_PATH = ReturnThisAssemblyPath();

        DB_PATH = ASSEMBLY_PATH + @"\Datastore\" + DB_FILENAME;
        try
        {
            DbProviderFactory fac = System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory.Instance;

            var conn = fac.CreateConnection();

            conn.ConnectionString = "data source =" + DB_PATH + @"\SQLiteDatabase.db";
            using (var m = new ReportsContext(conn))
            {
                try
                {
                    m.Reports.Add(new Datastore.Report() { reportTypeId = "1", reportType = "HL7", originalString = "orig10", processedString = "mod10" });
                    m.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {

                }
                var res = m.Reports.Find(111);
            }

        }catch(System.Exception ex)
        {

        }
```

I also tried `DbProviderFactory fac = System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory.Instance;`

But when it tried to add a record it fails with the following error

> Unable to determine the provider name for provider factory of type
>   'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory'. Make sure that the ADO.NET
>   provider is installed or registered in the application config.

Answer (score 0):

```
using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(string.Format("Data Source={0};Version=3;", <your_database_file_path>)))
{

}
```

Comment: While this code may help with the question, it is better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers tend to be less useful in the long run. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for some more info.